# editing dynamic navigation tabs of template

Tags: html, css, templates, tabs, navigation

I'm pretty new to coding particular to javascript, so sorry upfront for any dump ass questions.

what I'm trying to do is redesigning an template. I need to edit the length of the navigation tabs. I have a java script(tabs.js) which is automatically scaling the length of the tabs measured on the number of letters i guess.  Question is how can I set the length of the tabs similar, even when the word changes in the number of letters.

This is the javascript

```
tabs = {
```

init : function(){
   $('.tabs').each(function(){

```
var th=$(this),
 tContent=$('.tab-content',th),
 navA=$('.nav a',th)

tContent.not(tContent.eq(0)).hide()

navA.click(function(){
    var th=$(this),
    tmp=th.attr('href')
    tContent.not($(tmp.slice(tmp.indexOf('#'))).fadeIn(1000)).hide()
    $(th).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').find('span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);
    Cufon.refresh();
    return false;
});
```

Here is my html code

```
            <header>

               <nav>
                  <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#!/page_Home"><span></span><strong>EVENTS</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!/page_About"><span></span><strong>HISTORY</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!/page_Portfolio"><span></span><strong>IMPRESSIONS</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!/page_Services"><span></span><strong>BOOKING</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!/page_Contact"><span></span><strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </nav>
         </header>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.  Please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to recall something I read in the past....

.setTabSize(int Size)

I'm pretty sure that will help, or at least get you on the right track. Hopefully...